# How to lazy init async dabase pool, tokio, axum

Tags: rust

I want to lazy init a struct with async database pool once and use it everywhere

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Database {
    pub pool: PgPool,
}

impl Database {
    pub async fn init() -> Self {
        let pool = Database::create_db_pool().await;

        Database { pool }
    }

    pub async fn create_db_pool() -> PgPool {
        PgPoolOptions::new()
            .max_connections(20)
            .acquire_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))
            .connect(API_ENV.db_url)
            .await
            .expect("Can't connect to database")
    }
}
```

I can do this like so, but it requires to write `DATABASE.get().unwrap()` which I don't like:

```
pub static DATABASE: OnceCell<Database> = OnceCell::new();

async fn main() {
    let db = Database::init().await;
    DATABASE.set(db).unwrap();

    let db = DATABASE.get().unwrap();
}
```

Trying to do `block_on` as suggested in some examples

```
pub static DATABASE: Lazy<Database> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let pool: Database = Runtime::new()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async { Database::init().await });

    pool
});

async fn main() {
    let db = DATABASE.pool;
}
```

Leeds to an error:

> Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

---

Thanks to @Chayim Friedman I got an idea on how to do it:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Database {
    pub pool: PgPool,
}

impl Database {
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let pool = POOL.get().unwrap();

        Database { pool: pool.clone() }
    }

    pub async fn create_db_pool() -> PgPool {
        PgPoolOptions::new()
            .max_connections(20)
            .acquire_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))
            .connect(API_ENV.db_url)
            .await
            .expect("Can't connect to database")
    }
}

pub static DATABASE: Lazy<Database> = Lazy::new(Database::init);
pub static POOL: OnceCell<PgPool> = OnceCell::new();
```

main

```
async fn main() {
    let pool = Database::create_db_pool().await;
    POOL.set(pool).unwrap();
}
```

usage

```
fn anywhere() {
    let pool = &DATABASE.pool;
}
```

Comment: A solution most likely depends on your runtime wkhich you didn't specify. The error message sounds like `tokio` can you edit your question to clarify. If it is indeed `tokio` you should be able to use the current runtime to `block_on` with [`Handle::current`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.current).

Comment: @cafce25 it's tokio `Handle::current()
        .block_on(async { Database::init().await })` gives me the same exact error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, [`tokio` has its own `OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html):

```rust
static DATABASE: tokio::sync::OnceCell<PgPool> = tokio::sync::OnceCell::const_new();

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Database {
    pub pool: PgPool,
}

impl Database {
    pub async fn init() -> Self {
        let pool = Database::create_db_pool().await;

        Database { pool }
    }

    pub async fn create_db_pool() -> PgPool {
        DATABASE
            .get_or_init(|| async {
                PgPoolOptions::new()
                    .max_connections(20)
                    .acquire_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))
                    .connect(API_ENV.db_url)
                    .await
                    .expect("Can't connect to database")
            })
            .await
            .clone()
    }
}
```

([`sqlx::PgPool` has a cheap `Clone`](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/49ccc7ca3215fd6e96f38abb528446a894e3a561/sqlx-core/src/pool/mod.rs#L267).)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating singleton with `OnceCell` you can just pass shared references to all your components that need it. For example wrap your `Database` in `Arc` and use `Arc::clone` to pass it to all of your instances. Then you don't have a problem with lazy initialization. You just initialize `Database` and everything later can just use it through the pointer it got.

If you are writing some kind of backend server, and are using a web framework like `actix` or `axum`, you can very easily do that and pass references through `State` and then acquire it with *state extractor* in your handlers.

Comment: [`PgPool` is already an `Arc` internally](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/sqlx-core/src/pool/mod.rs#L267).